# Laravel base URL redirecting to /home for no reason

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-authentication

I'm learning laravel and I have a problem with my base url which is `http://localhost/`.

It keeps redirecting to `http://localhost/home` which is the base authentication route and since im not logged in, it redirects me to `http://localhost/login`.

I want `http://localhost/` to redirect to `http://localhost/blog/posts` as it should.

I'm doing this because in the future the base url will redirect to another page. Until then, I want to display the blog posts.

web.php

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'index',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@index',
]);

Route::get('/blog/posts', [
    'as' => 'blog',
    'uses' => 'BlogController@index'
]);

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@home'
]);
```

HomeController.php

```
public function home()
{
    return view('home');
}

public function index()
{
    return view('blog');
}
```

I hope I was clear enough, i'd be glad to give more info if needed.

### Problem solved:

Comment or remove `$this->middleware('auth');` in HomeController.php and add it in the route:

```
Route::get('/home', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@home'
])->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the HomeController `__construct() function` doesn't have an `auth middleware` inside, that would try to log you in first, then continue to check for the index function.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. I should have seen it,  I'm heedless I guess.